# How to set sessionstate in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

Is there any way to set sessionstate=readonly in classic asp?

We want to set sessionstate is readonly.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know there is no way in classic asp to set the session state to readonly like in asp.net.

you could either turn it on or off like described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120430225813/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244465/en-us)

an alternative is not to store session data in session variables but in a database. but in classic asp you have to do this manually....

Answer (score 0):

No session state is read/write, however just wrap-it-up with a function which prevents tampering. you could even prefix the session name with a 'mystical' value so tampering gets harder.

The problem lies in the fact that a certain moment in time, at a certain place in your code you MUST write, otherwise you can't user them at all.

So the place to look for the solution is:
- where is write allowed
- where is write NOT allowed

that is the real question (I think...)